# Converting a 2D array from decimal to binary

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm currently working on a genetic algorithm, and want to convert my "population" into binary from decimal, so I can do crossovers more easily.

I have an array of 70x71 array of numbers (a population of 70; each population member has 71 variables).

Is there a way I can map BaseForm[] onto each element, whilst keeping the array format?

I tried doing this:

```
population=RandomReal[1,{70,71}];
binaryPopulation = {};
For[i = 1, i <= 70, i++,
  For[j = 1, j <= 71, j++,
    AppendTo[binaryPopulation, BaseForm[population[[i, j]], 2]]
    ];
  ];
```

But this generates one large array (ie. not separated into 70 different members, it's just one long array).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: `Map[BaseForm[#, 2] &, population, {2}]`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica

Answer (score 3):

A **minimal** working example does not require a 70x71 array.

```
(population = RandomReal[1, {2, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(binaryPopulation = Map[{#, BaseForm[#, 2]} &, population, {2}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

However, [`BaseForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseForm.html) is a display form used for printing. Perhaps you want something like

```
(binaryPopulation = 
   Map[{#, FromDigits[RealDigits[#, 2]]} &, population, {2}]) // 
  MatrixForm
```

[image]

Or

```
(binaryPopulation = 
   Map[{#, {Numerator[
        r = FromDigits[RealDigits[#, 2]]], -Log10[Denominator[r]]}} &, 
    population, {2}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this answer the same as my comment to the OP?

Comment: Mechanically yes; however, I am suggesting that `BaseForm` may not be want is desired.

Comment: Good point Bob, newbies frequently apply `MatrixForm`, `TableForm`, ... to an expression and are surprised when subsequent evaluations fail to work as expected.

Comment: OTOH, I can't imagine wanting `FromDigits[RealDigits[#, 2]]` since it changes the numeric value. That is, I'd rather have my numbers be the number they represent. Also ``FromDigits[RealDigits[0.8455762478601447`, 2]]`` has an extra bit than ``RealDigits[0.8455762478601447`, 2]``. That darned base 10, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The direct way to translate array construction via a nested for loop is to use `Table`; see [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)

```
binaryPopulation = Table[BaseForm[population[[i, j]], 2], {i, 70}, {j, 71}];
```

`Map` as in [@RohitNamjoshi's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266169/using-a-module-on-all-elements-of-an-array#comment663513_266169) and [@BobHanlon's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/266170/4999) is the preferred functional-programming approach.

Another alternative is

```
binaryPopulation = Function[, BaseForm[#, 2], Listable][population];
```

Comment: To get a binary rational number, as in Bob Hanlon's answer, you could use `Function[, BaseForm[SetPrecision[#, Infinity], 2], Listable]`, since `SetPrecision[real, Infinity]` converts a floating-point `real` to its binary fraction.